# Find File in directory Using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want Get Matched Files in php I have try Many More Time 
for example ...

my directory files

```
    1.254450_abcd.mp3
    2.101215_apple.mp4
    3.102545_efgf.php
```

i find only number like this 254450

```
$mypath = "/files/" ;
$find = "254450" ;
//i  want get matched full name
echo "$filename" ;// get 254450_abcd.mp3

else
"file not found " ;
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your code seems to be mixed with normal description (check the formatting). Finding ways to locate files in a directory shouldn't be hard to research online, too, just throw the question at a random search engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `scandir` and `preg_grep`.

```
$mypath = "/files/" ;
$find = "254450" ;

$files = scandir($mypath);
$matches = preg_grep("/" . $find . "/", $files);
```

`$matches` is now an array with files matching $find

Here is a semi working example. I replaced scandir with your files in an array, just like scandir returns them.
https://3v4l.org/QullZ